# How does RFC define a sequence of characters?

Tags: rfc

Recently, I read some document on HTTP message from [RFC 7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230), and I saw the definition of HTTP message:

> HTTP-message   = start-line
> *( header-field CRLF )
> CRLF
> [ message-body ]

Click [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3:%7E:text=HTTP%2Dmessage%20%20%20%3D%20start%2Dline%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*(%20header%2Dfield%20CRLF%20)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CRLF%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%20message%2Dbody%20%5D) for more details.

I understand what the symbol * and [] in this expression mean, but I would like to know which kind of expression the RFC use to define a sequence of characters and the name of this kind of expression. Is this expression called ABNF?

Comment: Yes, it uses ABNF as described in [section 1.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-1.2).